# Editing a Question to Include a Comment Left by Asker

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, questions, comments

When a user immediately follows a question with a comment that is important to the understanding and answering of that question, should the comment be moved to the body of the question itself?

Shortly after asking the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23600582/concatenate-pandas-columns-under-new-multi-index-level), the OP posted a comment with some more information on what s/he had already tried:

> I've tried a few methods - eg for each data frame replace the columns with a multi-index like `.from_product(['ABC', columns])` and then concatenate along axis=1, without success...

Because I thought this comment should really have been part of the original question, I submitted [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4785767), which moved the comment, in full, to the question. The edit was rejected and the reason given by the three rejecting users was *This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post.*

Have I misunderstood the division of comments and questions? Should this really have been left to the comments? Or is this, perhaps, a case of reviewers not carefully reading the edit?

Comment: *"Or is this, perhaps, a case of reviewers not carefully reading the edit?"* <---

Comment: Glad it happens to others aswell.  "Or is this, perhaps, a case of reviewers not carefully reading the edit?" Is that really possible? :) Note, this is related: [Is it okay to edit an asker's comment into the question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294963/is-it-okay-to-edit-an-askers-comment-into-the-question)

Comment: Unfortunately, some reviewers are also very strict, rejecting 3/4 of the edits - maybe sometimes an edit that is totally fine with the community guidelines slips through.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's a case of reviewers not carefully reading the edit.

I see you've added this comment:

> Added OP's comment to post body

When such a comment is there, I always go to the question to verify if the suggested edit is indeed adding a comment from the OP to the question. If so, the edit is correct and I approve it.

I've applied the edit for you.

Comment: But what to do when the edit was mistakenly rejected for such a reason? Try it again, requesting for more care?

Comment: I'm also curious about that @try-catch-finally. I wanted to include content from two comments into an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/34075639) (if that's not publicly visible, [this is the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749416/check-whether-a-variable-is-a-string-in-ruby/7749428#7749428)). How should one proceed when this happens? Open a meta question every time can't be right.