# Editing a question to include asker's comment - how to phrase edit summary?

Tags: discussion, edits, rejected-edits

I've run into (or almost run into, and had an edit squeak by 3-2) the problem described [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254528/editing-a-question-to-include-a-comment-left-by-asker) a couple times, where an asker adds information critical to the question in a comment. I edit the information into the question itself with a reason along the lines of "added information from comment by OP", and the edit gets rejected or almost gets rejected on the grounds of:

> This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post.

The consensus on the linked question was that it was probably a case of reviewers not paying attention, but moving on to solutions:

How should I word an edit summary to clearly express the purpose (and source) of my edit without triggering snap reject votes (presumably over inclusion of the word "comment")?

Comment: Get to 2k rep, then you won't have this problem.

Comment: @BenVoigt If there's an entire system designed around suggesting and reviewing edits, saying "get out of the system" is not a solution to problems with the system. That's like having someone ask about a communication problem with a busy professor and telling them they should just graduate so they don't have to worry about it :P

Comment: There are also a ton of answers on meta that say certain types of edits should only be performed by 2k users, because the value of the edit is less than the cost of reviewing.  The value of incorporating comments is pretty low, since the information already does exist (in the comments), so there's no harm if it doesn't get done until it catches the attention of a 2k user.

Comment: @BenVoigt The whole problem is that the cost of reviewing is about 0.5s, either from robo-reviewers or people trying to race them to reject. And if it's an edit that's not worth reviewing, it should be rejected as too minor, but that's not what's happening. Incorporating information from comments is listed on the help page as a reason for editing; where is there a meta post that says it, specifically, is a type of edit that should be left to 2k+ users?

Answer (score 4):

From my auto-complete history:

> included extra information from OP found in comments to better clarify question