# Best practices on cutting a correct comment and pasting/processing it into its parent post when I don't have full editing privileges?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits, editing-help, specific-edit

So let's say there is a question (or answer) which has a comment I consider relevant to the question. I might have the idea to include it in the answer explaining something like

> [included extra information found in comments to clarify question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260327/4575793)

I thought this was best practices, I found [for example this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/292098/4575793) supporting my thought. (The same should be true for answers.) So I have done the following:

1. [**edited the answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/34428468) to include that comment
2. giving credit to the author of the comment
3. fixed other issues and did improvements
4. marked the said comment as "no longer needed"

---

I should note that I'm neither the author of the question, nor the answer I edited, nor the comment. What happened was

- flag 4 got marked as helpful and therefore accepted
- reviewer got confused as the comment I refer to no longer existed
- including the comment and the other improvements got rejected (both)

---

What's the best practices on that? I have some ideas:

1. leave comments as they are - downside: they can be deleted, comments are generally considered less important
2. not give credit and just append "Attention: this will mutate the original array." (which is to the general public, not the author btw)
3. skip other changes to make it more obvious to the reviewer - downside: violates rule "fix all that needs fixing" - this might be applicable to users with >2k rep and full edit privileges tho
4. don't mark the comment as deprecated, potentially remembering the suggestion threeish days later upon acception and flag it then - downside obvious: much more work
5. something else? I don't see how I could let a reviewer know that a comment needs deletion if the inclusion is accepted

Comment: Was the comment on the question? Why did you incorporate it into the answer then (and why particularly that answer, there are other answers that have the same issue)?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat The comment was definitely on an answer, presumably the one OP edited, because the comments contents reference shortcomings to a _solution_.

Comment: @TylerH maybe, although OP states the comment was on the question (typo?) and given there is a comment suggesting the use of `reverse` there it might just be possible that the comment under consideration was a reply to it.

Comment: If everything is going to be written in the answer, what's the purpose of comments then? That's what comments were made, asking for clarification and noting stuff so no one should really do such a thing (adding a comment to an answer) besides the answer's author -  they're free to do so as it's their answer but if they don't really do it then it shouldn't be done...... *that's what comments were made for anyway*

Comment: Also such a "Be aware that this will mutate the original array which can be an issue as **TheToto noted**." can be pretty confusing to new users. I mean when/where did TheToto note such a thing? Even me, if I was reading this answer, I'd wait for a second then oh... it was a comment then it got deleted so Imagine new users who don't know anything about the site already.

Comment: @Abdul No, the comment was on the answer, therefore Idea 1. You're right that other answers could also have been edited, but imho it's acceptable to just care for one question or answer at one moment in time. You're right that I confused Q for A once - it's edited now, but doesn't really change the topic.

Comment: I fully see the point of your second comment. But to the first [the](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260327/4575793) [two](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/292098/4575793) links from my question discuss among others, why you *should* add the comment to the answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The confusion is almost certainly from the fact that this was a suggested edit and had to go through review by other users who also almost certainly never saw the comment you flagged. The answer's author likely did see it, as they would've received a notification.

If I am going to include information from a comment I want to delete via NLN flags, I usually mention that in the tag description (e.g. "adding a comment from theToto so I can flag the comment as no longer needed"). This way the author information is preserved in the revision history but doesn't need to show up in the post body, which can just focus on the content, instead.

However, I also recommend such unusual edits wait until 2k so you don't add unfamiliar reviewers into the mix.

Ultimately, while in isolation the edit seemed like a good/well-intentioned one, I am not sure this was a good edit suggestion in the grand scheme of things. Not only is this answer repeating many others, but the comment's warning was also already present under most of the other answers of this solution. The right thing to do here was instead to downvote the answer for repeating existing solutions.

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion, you did right. The only problem is who handles what:

- "No longer needed" flag on comments are addressed by mods
- Edit are reviewed by users

After 2k rep, your edits will be definitive and will not be going through review. Until then I'd wait the edit to be reviewed (you should have a notification when that happens) before flagging the comment (if still present).

So I think you did good. You just had bad luck in timing for it to be consistent for all parties in the follow-up of your actions.