# Is it okay to edit an asker's comment into the question?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits, comments

[How does clipsToBounds work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449256/clipstobounds-how-does-it-work)

I was looking through some of my old answers, trying to see if there was anything that could be cleaned up, improved, or updated, and I came across this question.

This question & answer seems to have helped a handful of people, but the question itself in its current form isn't completely clear (I even originally posted a comment to this effect).  The question currently reads:

> I would like to know how to use this property clipsToBounds . I checked the App document but I don't really get it.

And there is an explanatory comment from the asker:

> If the property is YES, subviews must be clipped on bounds of the superview, so there is a case to see a part of the subview. If is NO, subviews can be clipped outside the superview?

I think the question could be improved if this comment were incorporated into the question.  Ordinarily, I might post a comment asking the asker to clean this up, but this question is a year and a half old.  What's the protocol here?  Is this something that's okay to do?

Comment: Related, but actually not a duplicate because it's about an edit that tried to add details from the comment section, that was rejected: [Editing a Question to Include a Comment Left by Asker](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254528/editing-a-question-to-include-a-comment-left-by-asker)

Comment: I'm tempted to ask my own question related to this one, but it's title would be "To what extent should a question be edited to add details from her/his comments?" but I wonder if this could be done here too? I often come across questions where _multiple_ comments of the OP add valuable details to the post (while to OP seems to be persistently ignoring requests to add the details by editing). On the other hand focussing on _to what extent_ and _is ignoring requests_ may make up / address a completely new topic.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If it really doesn't look like the OP is coming back then, yes please do edit the comment into the question.

Once you've done that delete any of your own comments and flag the rest as obsolete. It's better to flag each comment you think should be removed rather than flagging the question as you're not asking the moderator to make the decision on which comments should be removed and which should stay. We're not necessarily subject experts so we won't always know what's relevant and what's not.

Comment: Are you sure? Because that sometimes leads to a load of declines, even if the comments are all removed... at least, thus has been my experience. Other times, they were all accepted.

Comment: @Deduplicator It may depend on the moderator. I prefer not to have to sort through a dozen comments to see which ones can be removed - especially on a question where I'm not a subject expert. If *you* (the subject expert) can tell me what can go, then it makes my life a *lot* easier.

Comment: @Deduplicator - a single flag on the post may lead to **all** the comments being removed, which may not be what you want.

Comment: @ChrisF [Two years ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203211/flagging-multiple-comments-versus-flagging-the-whole-post-for-moderator-attentio/203215#comment647337_203215) you seemed to agree with Shog's post recommending pretty much the *exact opposite* policy. Have you changed your mind, has the moderator UI changed, am I wrong to interpret your comment there as implying full agreement with Shog, is it really the case that what's ideal is kind of messier than a simple "flag post" or "flag comments" instruction can convey, or something else?

Comment: @mark - I don't whether you can see my deleted answer on that question but I've been consistent in my preference for flagging each comment. Where I was agreeing with Shog was that you should be clear in your flags. Just saying "comment clean up required" will probably result in **all** the comments being removed. If only a few need to go, tell us which ones they are.

Comment: I think what you mean by, "If it really doesn't look like the OP is coming back then..." is really, "If it doesn't look like the OP is going to edit the details into the question..." I prefer the latter wording because the former might lead some users to think you're referring to inactivity on the account. There are also clear cut cases where I wouldn't bother to wait because the comment is so clearly vital to the question; answers referencing the content in the comment is a good indicator of that case. I try to stick true to the user's wording; if they don't like my edit, they can revise.

Answer (score -2):

As long as you're sure OP notices the edit, and that you're not interfering with what might be another edit on OP's part - sure, even if it looks like the OP is coming back. He can always revert it if he likes. Perhaps be extra-careful and prefix the text from the comment with some kind of a "**(copied from comment)**" marker so nobody gets confused.

Of course, if OP edits it back, leave it alone.

SO is, after all, a collaborative effort - not a help desk.

Comment: I don't like the edit of prefixing it with any sort of "copied from comment" non-sense.  SE isn't a network of forums, and posts should be littered with "Edit:" and such.  It should all read as if it were all posted at the same time originally.