# Is it OK to edit information from the OP's comments into the question?

Tags: discussion, edits

I was under the impression this was [allowed if necessary](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294963/is-it-okay-to-edit-an-askers-comment-into-the-question), but I've been [asked not to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33244911/get-the-timestamp-of-the-start-of-a-day-local-time?noredirect=1#comment55264110_33244911), partly because it was arguably a Wrong Question.

In this case, I had answered the question on the basis of a comment by OP.  Another user dupehammered it against a question which, in my opinion, is unambiguously a different question if we take the OP's comment into account.  So I voted to reopen, waited a while, and when that failed to work, re-voted to reopen and edited the OP's comment into the question.  I was then rolled back and told not to do that.

**Did I do the Right Thing here?**

Comment: Considering that his later comment indicates that he *is* actually trying to get the time for a given timezone, but that he just thinks that using an offset will be easier, so he's just doing that for now, the *actual* problem he has is *exactly* what the duplicate described, and providing a solution for an offset is not solving his actual problem and is harmful for both him and all future readers of the question.

Comment: @Servy Actually, I don't see that the OP *thinks* that it's easier using an offset. If it's really the requirement (as wrong as it is), should it be rollbacked?

Comment: @AndrewT. The OP said that he couldn't be bothered to deal with the timezone, meaning that there really is a timezone in his problem domain, not an offset, and he's under the (false) impression that he can just use an offset and have it be good enough.